# How to clone a Synchronised DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am syncing a bunch of objects from our SF instance into our SFMC instance in the top level BU using MC connect. I now need to clone these Synchronised DE's into the child BU's so that I can provide filtered data to the child BU's.

Problem is that you don't get the option to copy a DE from a Synchronised DE and each of my Synchronised DE's have about 100-200 fields, so it's going to be a pain to recreate them manually for each BU.

Is there a better way of cloning a Synchronised DE ? Or even another way to provide filtered data to child BU's?

Answer (score 2):

As you can't share a Synchronized DE and as you can't create a new Standard DE from an existing Synchronized DE, I can't see any other method than manually creating it. You could potentially use an available API method, but by the time you've written the code required, it would be quicker to create the DE manually.

Once you have created a new DE with the same schema as your Synchronized DE, I would:

1. Move the new DE to the Shared folder.
2. Create an automation in your Parent BU that uses a query to populate the shared DE from the fields in your Synchronized DE.

You can then access this Shared DE from child BUs (assuming you have assigned the correct sharing permissions).

Comment: One of my colleagues developed a tampermonkey (Chrome extension) script that adds a create table button to the data extension detail page. This is pretty handy. I'll check if she's willing to share it with you guys.